# how to control horizontal scroll bar(in IE browser) using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

how to capture the scroll bar actions using QTP. i want to move the horizontal scroll bar to left using VBscript . Im trying it for IE browser. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance
Kamesh.

Answer (score 0):

To set scroll position in IE, try:

```
document.body.scrollTop = 150;
```

There are some good notes in Mozilla's documentation for cross-browser support:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollY

**Edit:**

I read on MSDN that scrollTop works in standards mode and for quirks mode you may neeed to use doScroll(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536414(v=vs.85).aspx

```
Browser("Qtp").Page("Quick Test Professional").Object.body.doScroll("scrollbarPageLeft")
```

Sorry, no QTP to try on myself.

Comment: I tried this Browser("creationtime:=0").Page("index:=0").document.body,scrollLeft=200  got the error message as Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Browser(...).page(...).document'

Answer (score 0):

Use "Object" instead of "document". This works -

```
Browser("Qtp").Page("Quick Test Professional").Object.body.scrollLeft = 200
Browser("Qtp").Page("Quick Test Professional").Object.body.scrollTop = 200
```

Comment: I used this Browser("Qtp").Page("Quick Test Professional").Object.body.scrollLeft = 200   . It doesnt throw any error but makes no difference..the horizontal scroll bar is in same place(right side). Do i need to add any piece of code to make it work????